# How can I get a list of types that implement a particular trait in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

I want to know a struct that implements `std::io::Write`; is it described in some document?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you lookup the [API for `std`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/) you can search for your trait there (e.g. [`std::io::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html)).

When you scroll down to the section "[Implementors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#implementors)" you will see all structs/enums that implement that trait in `std`.

To get a better overview, you can use the <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> keys to collapse all sections and have a nice overview, e.g.

[image: Write implementors overview]

Comment: It's important to note that types outside of the standard library can implement `Write` (or more generically, any trait from any crate can be implemented by a type in another crate). The best thing to do is is look at your own locally-generated documentation in your project (`cargo doc`) to ensure that types from other crates you are using are included.

Comment: If it possible to get it programmatically? Like getting a `Vec<Trait>` when the trait and all the implements are local?

Comment: @undefined Rust doesn't have Reflection builtin, therefore I highly doubt it. Or maybe I'm missunderstanding your question. You better should create a new one :)