# What are all the different error types in Rust?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm learning Rust and can't find a list of all error types. When a function is returning a `Result`, does the standard library have a group of predefined errors available for use?

I know custom error types can be made in Rust, is that the solution? Make all custom errors types?

Comment: See https://stevedonovan.github.io/rust-gentle-intro/6-error-handling.html. Custom error types must implement `Error` and `Display`. But `Result` allows using any type for errors, even strings and base types like `i32`.

Comment: Well thanks everyone, this helps me understand the Result type and Rust's errors better than the documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not well defined what "an error type" would mean, so no, there is no global list of errors.

If you mean "is there a list of all the types that are used as `Result::Err`, the answer is still no. There are methods like [`slice::binary_search`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search) which return `Result<usize, usize>`. Is `usize` to be considered an error type? What if a `Result::Err` is constructed entirely inside of a function and never leaves it; is that type considered an error type? What about a generic type that contains a `Result<i32, E>`; should any concrete `E` be called an error type?

If you mean "is there a list of all the types that implement `std::error::Error`, then the answer is "kind of". See [How can I get a list of structs that implement a particular trait in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55216559/155423) for details.

> does the standard library have a group of predefined errors

Yes.

> available for use

Sometimes. [`io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html) allows you to construct your own error value, but [`num::ParseIntError`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.ParseIntError.html) does not.

> is that the solution? Make all custom errors types?

Generally, yes.

See also:

- [How do you define custom `Error` types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42584368/155423)

Answer (score 5):

Result types are often aliased in the standard library. If you see a function in the standard library documentation, you can click on `Result`, which should lead you to the aliased type (e.g. [`std::io::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html))
You can then see which kind of `Error` is used in the `Result`.

The documentation also has a [list](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#implementors) of all enums and structs in the standard library that implement the `Error` trait.

Answer (score 1):

a list, although not complete, can be found at
https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/std/error/trait.Error.html